# 2 Buttons in custom listview one should be invisible

Tags: listview, visibility

I have a little problem due to ListRecycling,
the problem is that i have a list item populated with a couple of textviews and 2 buttons.
one button is always visible (has always text), but the other something is empty so should also not be shown.

i have tried a couple of things, tried to adjust the implementation for checkboxes in a custom list but with no luck.

```
public class PokeDexListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context ctx;
LayoutInflater LInflator;
ArrayList<PokeDexListItems> pokeDexList;

public static final String ROW_ID = "row_id"; // Intent extra key

public PokeDexListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PokeDexListItems> list) {
    ctx = context;
    pokeDexList = list;
    LInflator = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return pokeDexList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return pokeDexList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    PokeDexListItems pokeDexListItems = pokeDexList.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LInflator.inflate(R.layout.nat_dex_list_item, null);
    }

    TextView pokeTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameDexTv);
    TextView natDexTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.natDexTv);
    Button type1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.type1Btn);
    Button type2 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.type2Btn);

    ImageView pokeSprite = (ImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.pokeSpriteIV);

    pokeTv.setText(pokeDexListItems.getpokeName());
    natDexTv.setText(pokeDexListItems.getNatDex());
    type1.setText(pokeDexListItems.getType1());
    type2.setText(pokeDexListItems.getType2());

    AssetManager assetManager = ctx.getAssets();

    try {

        InputStream ims = assetManager.open("pokes/"
                + pokeDexListItems.getImageIndex() + ".gif");

        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);

        pokeSprite.setImageDrawable(d);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (type1.getText().toString().contains("Bug")) {
        type1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bug_button_border);
    } else if (type1.getText().toString().contains("Dark")) {
        type1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dark_button_border);
    } else if (type1.getText().toString().contains("Dragon")) {
        type1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dragon_button_border);
    } else if (type1.getText().toString().contains("Electric")) {
        type1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.electric_button_border);
    } else if (type1.getText().toString().contains("Fairy")) {
        type1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fairy_button_border);
    } else if (type1.getText().toString().contains("Fighting")) {
        type1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fight_button_border);
    } else if (type1.getText().toString().contains("Fire")) {
        type1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fire_button_border);
    } else if (type1.getText().toString().contains("Flying")) {
        type1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.flying_button_border);
    } else if (type1.getText().toString().contains("Ghost")) {
        type1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ghost_button_border);
    } else if (type1.getText().toString().contains("Grass")) {
        type1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grass_button_border);
    } else if (type1.getText().toString().contains("Ground")) {
        type1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ground_button_border);
    } else if (type1.getText().toString().contains("Ice")) {
        type1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ice_button_border);
    } else if (type1.getText().toString().contains("Normal")) {
        type1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.normal_button_border);
    } else if (type1.getText().toString().contains("Poison")) {
        type1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.poison_button_border);
    } else if (type1.getText().toString().contains("Psychic")) {
        type1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.psychic_button_border);
    } else if (type1.getText().toString().contains("Rock")) {
        type1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rock_button_border);
    } else if (type1.getText().toString().contains("Steel")) {
        type1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.steel_button_border);
    } else if (type1.getText().toString().contains("Water")) {
        type1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.water_button_border);
    }

    if (type2.getText().toString().contains("Bug")) {
        type2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bug_button_border);
    } else if (type2.getText().toString().contains("Dark")) {
        type2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dark_button_border);
    } else if (type2.getText().toString().contains("Dragon")) {
        type2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dragon_button_border);
    } else if (type2.getText().toString().contains("Electric")) {
        type2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.electric_button_border);
    } else if (type2.getText().toString().contains("Fairy")) {
        type2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fairy_button_border);
    } else if (type2.getText().toString().contains("Fighting")) {
        type2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fight_button_border);
    } else if (type2.getText().toString().contains("Fire")) {
        type2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fire_button_border);
    } else if (type2.getText().toString().contains("Flying")) {
        type2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.flying_button_border);
    } else if (type2.getText().toString().contains("Ghost")) {
        type2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ghost_button_border);
    } else if (type2.getText().toString().contains("Grass")) {
        type2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grass_button_border);
    } else if (type2.getText().toString().contains("Ground")) {
        type2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ground_button_border);
    } else if (type2.getText().toString().contains("Ice")) {
        type2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ice_button_border);
    } else if (type2.getText().toString().contains("Normal")) {
        type2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.normal_button_border);
    } else if (type2.getText().toString().contains("Poison")) {
        type2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.poison_button_border);
    } else if (type2.getText().toString().contains("Psychic")) {
        type2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.psychic_button_border);
    } else if (type2.getText().toString().contains("Rock")) {
        type2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rock_button_border);
    } else if (type2.getText().toString().contains("Steel")) {
        type2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.steel_button_border);
    } else if (type2.getText().toString().contains("Water")) {
        type2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.water_button_border);
    } else {

        type2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

    final int tag = pokeDexListItems.getRowIdTag();
    pokeTv.setTag(tag);

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                Intent viewPoke = new Intent(ctx, PokedexEntry.class);

                // pass the selected contact's row ID as an extra with the
                // Intent
                viewPoke.putExtra(ROW_ID, getItemId(tag));

                ctx.startActivity(viewPoke); // start the ViewBook Activity
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "This entry does not exist anymore!!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

}
```

what i get now with this code is, the correct view,
but the moment i start scrolling all the seconds buttons get invisible...
not really what i need xD

any help is appreciated,
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem, after a couple of trial and errors i tried to add the Visibility(View.VISIBLE) to the other "if statements",
see my answer for clearer understanding ^^

```
public class PokeDexListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context ctx;
LayoutInflater LInflator;
ArrayList<PokeDexListItems> pokeDexList;

public static final String ROW_ID = "row_id"; // Intent extra key

public PokeDexListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PokeDexListItems> list) {
    ctx = context;
    pokeDexList = list;
    LInflator = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return pokeDexList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return pokeDexList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView pokeSprite;
    TextView pokeTv;
    TextView natDexTv;
    Button type1;
    Button type2;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    PokeDexListItems pokeDexListItems = pokeDexList.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LInflator.inflate(R.layout.nat_dex_list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.pokeTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameDexTv);
        holder.natDexTv = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.natDexTv);
        holder.type1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.type1Btn);
        holder.type2 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.type2Btn);

        holder.pokeSprite = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.pokeSpriteIV);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.pokeTv.setText(pokeDexListItems.getpokeName());
    holder.natDexTv.setText(pokeDexListItems.getNatDex());
    holder.type1.setText(pokeDexListItems.getType1());
    holder.type2.setText(pokeDexListItems.getType2());

    AssetManager assetManager = ctx.getAssets();

    try {

        InputStream ims = assetManager.open("pokes/"
                + pokeDexListItems.getImageIndex() + ".gif");

        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);

        holder.pokeSprite.setImageDrawable(d);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (holder.type1.getText().toString().contains("Bug")) {
        holder.type1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bug_button_border);
    } else if (holder.type1.getText().toString().contains("Dark")) {
        holder.type1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dark_button_border);
    } else if (holder.type1.getText().toString().contains("Dragon")) {
        holder.type1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dragon_button_border);
    } else if (holder.type1.getText().toString().contains("Electric")) {
        holder.type1
                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.electric_button_border);
    } else if (holder.type1.getText().toString().contains("Fairy")) {
        holder.type1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fairy_button_border);
    } else if (holder.type1.getText().toString().contains("Fight")) {
        holder.type1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fight_button_border);
    } else if (holder.type1.getText().toString().contains("Fire")) {
        holder.type1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fire_button_border);
    } else if (holder.type1.getText().toString().contains("Flying")) {
        holder.type1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.flying_button_border);
    } else if (holder.type1.getText().toString().contains("Ghost")) {
        holder.type1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ghost_button_border);
    } else if (holder.type1.getText().toString().contains("Grass")) {
        holder.type1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grass_button_border);
    } else if (holder.type1.getText().toString().contains("Ground")) {
        holder.type1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ground_button_border);
    } else if (holder.type1.getText().toString().contains("Ice")) {
        holder.type1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ice_button_border);
    } else if (holder.type1.getText().toString().contains("Normal")) {
        holder.type1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.normal_button_border);
    } else if (holder.type1.getText().toString().contains("Poison")) {
        holder.type1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.poison_button_border);
    } else if (holder.type1.getText().toString().contains("Psychic")) {
        holder.type1
                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.psychic_button_border);
    } else if (holder.type1.getText().toString().contains("Rock")) {
        holder.type1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rock_button_border);
    } else if (holder.type1.getText().toString().contains("Steel")) {
        holder.type1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.steel_button_border);
    } else if (holder.type1.getText().toString().contains("Water")) {
        holder.type1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.water_button_border);
    }

    if (holder.type2.getText().toString().contains("Bug")) {
        holder.type2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bug_button_border);
        holder.type2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else if (holder.type2.getText().toString().contains("Dark")) {
        holder.type2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dark_button_border);
        holder.type2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else if (holder.type2.getText().toString().contains("Dragon")) {
        holder.type2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dragon_button_border);
        holder.type2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else if (holder.type2.getText().toString().contains("Electric")) {
        holder.type2
                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.electric_button_border);
        holder.type2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else if (holder.type2.getText().toString().contains("Fairy")) {
        holder.type2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fairy_button_border);
        holder.type2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else if (holder.type2.getText().toString().contains("Fight")) {
        holder.type2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fight_button_border);
        holder.type2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else if (holder.type2.getText().toString().contains("Fire")) {
        holder.type2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fire_button_border);
        holder.type2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else if (holder.type2.getText().toString().contains("Flying")) {
        holder.type2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.flying_button_border);
        holder.type2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else if (holder.type2.getText().toString().contains("Ghost")) {
        holder.type2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ghost_button_border);
        holder.type2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else if (holder.type2.getText().toString().contains("Grass")) {
        holder.type2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grass_button_border);
        holder.type2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else if (holder.type2.getText().toString().contains("Ground")) {
        holder.type2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ground_button_border);
        holder.type2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else if (holder.type2.getText().toString().contains("Ice")) {
        holder.type2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ice_button_border);
        holder.type2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else if (holder.type2.getText().toString().contains("Normal")) {
        holder.type2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.normal_button_border);
        holder.type2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else if (holder.type2.getText().toString().contains("Poison")) {
        holder.type2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.poison_button_border);
        holder.type2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else if (holder.type2.getText().toString().contains("Psychic")) {
        holder.type2
                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.psychic_button_border);
        holder.type2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else if (holder.type2.getText().toString().contains("Rock")) {
        holder.type2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rock_button_border);
        holder.type2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else if (holder.type2.getText().toString().contains("Steel")) {
        holder.type2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.steel_button_border);
        holder.type2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else if (holder.type2.getText().toString().contains("Water")) {
        holder.type2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.water_button_border);
        holder.type2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else {
        holder.type2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    final int tag = pokeDexListItems.getRowIdTag();
    holder.pokeTv.setTag(tag);

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                Intent viewPoke = new Intent(ctx, PokedexEntry.class);

                // pass the selected contact's row ID as an extra with the
                // Intent
                viewPoke.putExtra(ROW_ID, getItemId(tag));

                ctx.startActivity(viewPoke); // start the ViewBook Activity
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "This entry does not exist anymore!!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

}
```